# What does public mean for a variable?

Tags: solidity

Example:

```
address public owner;
```

Also, if we don't make a variable public manually, what is the default, private?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/01/02/making-smart-contracts-with-public-variables/ for a full explanation.

Yes, the default visibility for state variables is `internal`(as per [v0.8.4](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.4/contracts.html#visibility-and-getters)). Marking it `public` makes it easy to read the variable in a DApp or from another smart contract.